# why external formatted disk_log error?

Tags: erlang

I try to use the disk_log module.

`format = internal` is ok, `format = external` produces error message

```
-module(abiud_log_test).
-compile([{parse_transform, lager_transform}]).

-export([log_test/0]).

log_test()->
    File = "/tmp/test1.log",
    Cmd = "rm " ++ File,
    os:cmd(Cmd),
    Log = 'equipment',
    A =  [{name,Log},{file,File},{type,halt},{format,external},{mode,read_write}],
    {ok,B} = disk_log:open(A),
    lager:debug("abiud_log_test_log_test_1:~p",[B]),
    ok = disk_log:log(B,"aaa"),
    ok = disk_log:log(B,"aaa_1"),
    ok = disk_log:close(B),
    ok.
```

test result is as follows:

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)74> abiud_log_test:log_test().
* 3: syntax error before: abiud_log_test
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)74> abiud_log_test:log_test().
2014-05-10 14:02:52.234 [debug] |abiud|abiud_log_test|log_test|13|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|abiud_log_test_log_test_1:equipment
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    {error,{format_external,equipment}}
     in function  abiud_log_test:log_test/0 (src/abiud_log_test.erl, line 14)
```

format = internal

```
-module(abiud_log_test).
-compile([{parse_transform, lager_transform}]).

-export([log_test/0]).

log_test()->
    File = "/tmp/test1.log",
    Cmd = "rm " ++ File,
    os:cmd(Cmd),
    Log = 'equipment',
    A =  [{name,Log},{file,File},{type,halt},{format,internal},{mode,read_write}],
    {ok,B} = disk_log:open(A),
    lager:debug("abiud_log_test_log_test_1:~p",[B]),
    ok = disk_log:log(B,"aaa"),
    ok = disk_log:log(B,"aaa_1"),
    ok = disk_log:close(B),
    ok.
```

The result is ok as follows:

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)75> abiud_log_test:log_test().
2014-05-10 14:15:57.913 [debug] |abiud|abiud_log_test|log_test|13|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|Undefined|abiud_log_test_log_test_1:equipment
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

For the external format you should use disk_log:blog/2 instead, as the disk_log docs say at http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/disk_log.html#log-2: "The log/2 function is used for internally formatted logs, and blog/2 for externally formatted logs"

Note that the docs also say "There is no check to ensure this, it is entirely the responsibility of the caller.".